# Cannot permanently set GIT_SSH variable in Git for Windows 10

Tags: git, gitlab, openssh

Previously I had Git and PuTTY installed on my Windows 10 machine. Now I am switching to Windows OpenSSH. The problem I am running into is that Git Environmental Variable is stuck with `C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe` in GIT_SSH.

I have uninstalled Git and PuTTY, deleted the left behind directories. Change any registry entry I can find for Git or PuTTY but every time I install Git and tell it to use OpenSSH, it still has teh GIT_SSH variable set to PuTTY.

If I try `git pull` I get an error

```
error: cannot spawn C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

However if I us the following everything works fine

```
unset GIT_SSH
git pull
```

So the question is, where do I permanently clear the GIT_SSH?

I have read many suggestions to add a global system variable to Windows but that has not worked.

Comment: Environment variables aren't spontaneously set, so somewhere there is a setting that sets this variable, find this and remove it from there. You should check the system environment variables. Hit Win-button and type in "environment variables" and open the suggested item to check.

Answer (score -1):

Either this variable is set as a User or System environment variable, or it is set in your `~/.bashrc` in a Putty session.

In a CMD, check the former by typing `set git`: any (user or system) environment variable with GITxxx will show up.

In a Putty session, type `env|grep -i git` for a similar check.